# Why does Redshift ignore length when grouping by VARCHAR of only spaces?

Tags: group-by, redshift, varchar

Imagine I have a column `name` that is `n` rows and the `nth` entry is equal to `REPEAT(' ', n)`. For `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table` I would expect to receive `n` rows because each name is unique by definition. For dialects like BigQuery and Snowflake, I do receive this. However for Redshift I only receive one row. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

In database systems it is common, when comparing character values of unequal lengths, to pad the shorter string with spaces before the comparison. Indeed, Redshift [documentation says this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html):

> Trailing blanks in CHAR values are always semantically insignificant. They are disregarded when you compare two CHAR values, not included in LENGTH calculations, and removed when you convert a CHAR value to another string type.
>
> Trailing spaces in VARCHAR and CHAR values are treated as semantically insignificant when values are compared.

In other words, all blank `name`s look the same to Redshift.

Comment: Ah ok. I don't like that but I guess I have no choice but to accept it. Thank you for your prompt and helpful response.